# Ubuntu libstdc++6 downgrade to libstdc++5

Tags: ubuntu

i'm working with GWT under Ubuntu 12.10 using Intellij IDEA. Some time ago the idea's built-in debugger began to crash with this error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so: undefined symbol: PL_ClearArenaPool
```

I've google it for a bit, and it seems to be that it used to work fine with libstdc++5, but my system recently updated and now i've got a libstdc++6 both with libstdc++5 (according to Synaptic). I can't remove libstdc++6 'cause it seems to remove almost all packages in my system. So how can i safely downgrade to libstdc++5, or are there any other ways to solve my problem with debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it downloading `libstdc++.so.5` from [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libstdc++5/download) and then installing it from the command line:

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++5_3.3.6-20_amd64.deb
```

Now I have both `libstdc++.so.5` and `libstdc++.so.6` installed.